# How to create modified date column on Pyspark table?

Tags: database, pyspark, triggers, bigdata, delta-lake

I need to make delta table in Pyspark with 'modifiedDate' column. when row updates modifiedDate's value should change to current time. I thought about making a trigger, but couldn't find any information about using them in Pyspark with delta tables. how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as trigger in Delta tables. You're doing all modifications using the code, and you need to use code to add this column when doing the [MERGE operation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge).   Overall workflow may look as following:

- you have data without `modifiedDate` column
- you add this column setting it to the current timestamp
- you're performing UPSERT (update of existing & insert of new) of data using the MERGE operation. For that you need to define a primary key that will be used to identify unique records.

Something like this (not tested)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from delta.tables import *

# this is your input data
df = ...
# add a column to it
input = df.withColumn("modifiedDate", F.current_timestamp())

destination = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '<path-to-data>')
destination.alias('dest') \
  .merge(
    input.alias('updates'),
    # use 'and' if you have multiple columns in primary key
    'dest.id = updates.id'  
  ) \
  .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
  .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
  .execute()
```